# When a user logs in it always goes to edit-your-profile page

Tags: joomla-3.x, login

Joomla version: Joomla! 3.10.1 Stable

PHP: 7.4

This joomla website doesn't have many plugins. I only have OneSocial plugin.

Anyways, I am willing to try any suggestions at this point, I have tried to back-up my joomla files and do a full reinstall, but the issue is still there.

When a registered user logs into the front-end of the joomla site, they get redirected to the edit-my-profile page, and ANY other URL, with the logged-in user, always redirects to edit-my-profile page. Even manually trying to visit any other URL gets redirected to edit-my-profile page.

Any tips on how to debug or read some logs?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if core "System - Privacy Consent" plugin is enabled. Users are required to agree with privacy policy in their profiles before they can use the site.

Comment: okay, let me try that and save the profile on a throw-away account!